# Status bar icon disappear after switching wallpaper (Appkit on MacOS 14)

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

I'm developing a MacOS app with a status bar item:

```swift
class StatusBar {
  var statusBar: NSStatusBar!
  var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!
  var settingsWindow: NSWindow?

  init() {
    statusBar = NSStatusBar()
    statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(
      withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength
    )
    statusBarItem.image = NSImage(
      systemSymbolName: "magnifyingglass.circle.fill",
      accessibilityDescription: nil
    )
  }
}
```

What I find is that, everything works fine initially, but **after I switch the wallpaper, the menu bar icon would just disappear**. See the following video:

https://vimeo.com/925727584?share=copy

Thanks!